# How to make gmail standard work in Icecat (v.17) - JavaScript problem

Tags: firefox, icecat

I want to try **Icecat** browser (I like having different yet similar browsers, so I want this beside Firefox).

To install

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuzilla-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update
>   && sudo apt-get install icecat -y

[image]

but then:

[image]

But Java is enabled

[image]

the list of plugins is the same in Icecat and Firefox, where gmail works fine.

what could be the matter?

Comment: yes i liked it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icecat comes with an enabled extension ([GNU LibreJS](https://www.gnu.org/software/librejs/)) that "blocks nonfree nontrivial JavaScript while allowing JavaScript that is free and/or trivial".

[image]

Disabling the addon solves the problem reported here.